# Getting Genymotion to run with homebrew/cask installed VirtualBox

Tags: android-studio, virtualbox, genymotion, homebrew-cask

I tried to get Genymotion running through Android Studio with VirtualBox installed through homebrew Cask. When trying to launch Genymotion through Android Studio using the `Genymotion Device Manager` button in the toolbar, I get the error `Genymotion: Initialize Engine: failed` in the event log, which seems to be the error related to when VirtualBox isn't installed.

Running Genymotion on its own outside of Android Studio works perfectly fine.

I was able to fix this by uninstalling VirtualBox from Cask and reinstalling with the `.dmg` provided by VirtualBox themselves. That's fine for me right now, but I am wondering how one would get a Cask-installed VirtualBox linked up to Android Studio.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have installed [Homebrew](http://sourabhbajaj.com/mac-setup/Homebrew/README.html).

```
brew cask install virtualbox

brew cask install genymotion
```